# How can I disable the Desktop Background Slide Show in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In the new Windows 7 RTM, I can't see a place in Control Panel->Appearance and Personalization->Personalization to disable the desktop background slideshow feature.  You can change what's included, so I suppose if you chose a single background that would do it.

Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deselecting all images but one should do the trick.

A more [sophisticated way would be:](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/disable-the-desktop-background-slide-show-in-windows-7/)

**Pause the Desktop Background Slide Show**

- Open the Control Panel in the Start menu.
- Open Power Options in the Control Panel.

Note: If Power Options is not available, change View by to Large icons at the top right of the Control Panel.

- Click Change plan settings next to the power plan you want to edit.
- Click Change advanced power settings.
- Click Change settings that are currently unavailable to unlock the advanced power settings.

[image]

- Set Slide show under Desktop background settings to Paused and then click OK to save the changes.

[image]

Comment: +1  Thanks.  Seems like it should be easier but I'll take what I can get ;)

Comment: +1. This is the only way in windows 10.

Comment: Bhojendra, actually it didn't work for me in win 10, so I added another answer, see below.

Answer (score 4):

It's here:

[image]

Choosing several background images (the checkboxes appear as soon as you hover the mouse over the image) turns on the scroll list below the image list:

[image]

By choosing a single image you can turn the slide show off.

Comment: @TFM: Your last screenshot looks slightly different than mine.  I don't have the "When using battery power, pause the slideshow to save power" option.  Is that Windows 7 RTM or one of the release candidates?

Comment: @C-Pound Guru: I'm (still) using the RC on my laptop.

Comment: **@C-Pound Guru:** If your PC doesn't have a battery (ie.: desktop without ups), that option is not shown.

Comment: @Andrew Moore:  Thanks...didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Just select no more than one image, and there will be no slideshow =)