# windows 10 disable "change picture every"

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I have two background pictures, one landscape, one portrait. I don't want them to change.

Unfortunately, when I go to `Personalization`, and click change picture every, there is no option for it.

[image]

I want each monitor to stay with the background I configured for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable the Desktop Background Slide Show in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/23707/how-can-i-disable-the-desktop-background-slide-show-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Set it as a picture and not a slide show? Save both pictures as one picture and set to same resolution as monitors combined. Set to centre.  Not a fix but a workaround.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Glad to see you pitching in to help. A common mistake new users make is to answer without details of how to actually resolves the issue. Answers should be detailed and include references, as needed. Please take a few minutes to edit your answer to include steps of how to resolve the problem. If you need additional help, read [How do I write a good answer?](//superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).